# Как в JDBC создать запрос на поиск идентичного текста в базе данных,где текст передается из переменной типа String

Tags: sql, база-данных, jdbc, h2

Как проверить идентичность значения в базе данных h2 с значением переменной типа `String`?

```
r=stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE LOGIN ='data'");
```

Вместо текста data должна передаваться переменная типа String:

`r=stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE LOGIN =login");`

Использование `PreparedStatement` тоже не получилось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Именно вот так:

```
String str = "Alex";
r = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE LOGIN = '" + str + "';");
```

Comment: String s="qwer";
r=stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE LOGIN ='"+s+"';");
            while(r.next()){
                System.out.print(r.getString("Login"));
            }

Comment: не выводит никаких результатов хотя в базе данных есть запись с таким login;

Comment: @Георгий давай тогда на почту пришли код, так будет проще vladislavkhripkov@mail.ru